# Only colour half a div with CSS gradients

Tags: html, css

is it possible to colour only half a div white from the left and the other side green? I want to do this on the 19th date in this graphic

[image]

```css
td.specialDate:first-of-type {
   background-image: linear-gradient(left, lightgreen, lightgreen 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, lightgreen, lightgreen 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);
}
```

Comment: You wanna have a look on this: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try something like this:

```
background: green;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, green 0%, white 50%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, green 0%, white 50%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, green 0%, white 50%);
```

[Here](http://codepen.io/davideghz/pen/akaPrv) a link to a code sample on CodePen

You can go crazy with gradients on [this](http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor) nice website

## EDIT

If you want to color exactly half of the div, w/o the shade/gradient, use this code:

```
background: green;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, green 50%, white 50%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, green 50%, white 50%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, green 50%, white 50%);
```

if you want a diagonal from bottom left to top right, use this code:

```
background: green;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, green 50%, white 50%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, green 50%, white 50%);
background: linear-gradient(45deg, green 50%, white 50%);
```

Check the linked [Codepen](http://codepen.io/davideghz/pen/akaPrv) sample for the updated code sample.

Comment: Is there a way to cleanly finish so it finishes exactly 50% down the line so I can show 1/2 day on the calendar, or even bottom left to top-right?

Comment: hey @merch89 - did it solve your problem? let us know :)

Comment: Hi David! I've tried this with rgba but didn't work. Any clues?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, and you're not too far off with the gradient:

```css
html, body {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

div {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

div {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, lightgreen 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

And [here's a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t84fax9x/) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check this code.

```
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 50%, #0f0 50%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 50%,#0f0 50%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 50%,#0f0 50%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/a9uzumpf/)

Comment: Thanks its help for me

Answer (score 0):

Use this in CSS:

```
div {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(
      to right, 
      red,
      red 50%,
      green 50%,
      green 100%
    );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible.

[Here it is](http://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator#'%5C-moz%5C-linear%5C-gradient%5C%28left%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28144%5C%2C238%5C%2C144%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%200%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28120%5C%2C235%5C%2C120%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%2050%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%2852%5C%2C237%5C%2C52%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%20100%5C%25%5C%29%5C%3B') . You can copy the code by clicking "Copy Text" below. It's too long to post here.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: The values are already set in the link. All he needs to do is copy and paste it. But yeah, I get the point